# Are there any books on the history of economic, marketing and design choices of LEGO and the company?

Tags: history, books

I am interested in the history of economic, marketing and design choices made by the company, that shaped the product line (or individual sets) and the LEGO experience that we all love. Preferably about the post-2000 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there actually is a book that discusses just this subject AND it's primarily focused on the post-2000 years:

Brick by Brick: How LEGO Rewrote the Rules of Innovation and Conquered the Global Toy Industry by David Robertson.

I highly recommend this book - while professing to be a business book, it gives huge insight into the companies design-reasoning and history.

Amazon Link [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307951618).

Comment: Thanks Ash, I'll order it for sure! Will post some review when done, but I'll keep this post open not to discourage other answerers (hopefully, there are more books on the topic).

Comment: @IstvánZachar did you like the book?

Comment: I have read the book, and despite the often sensational journalistic-style writing, I've learnt interesting historical details about the company. It does not discuss set development (specific or general) in detail. I nevertheless recommend the book for those interested in the economic decisions behind the company's near-catastrophic era in the early 2000's. Especially, that I have found no other book about the topic.